# ipc address bind error with 'Operation not permitted' in docker

Tags: python, docker

I got an error "Operation not permitted" when running the following python codes in docker

system: windows10
software: docker-desktop 2.0.0.3 (31259) Build: 8858db3
python: 3.6.8

```py
#pip3 install pyzmq
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket_to_others = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket_to_others.bind('ipc://test')


#socket_to_others.bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:7777')   #no error with tcp address
```

Comment: what command did you run to get that error ?

Comment: run docker with `docker run --rm --ipc=host --privileged -it --name test -v G:\pj\test:/data/www:rw image_name sh` and then type `python test.py`(the code above)

Comment: You can try to add option `--privileged` in your `docker run` command

Comment: I've added it already

Comment: I think your issue relates to volume, you can found it here https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/74#issuecomment-238918488

Comment: What's your base image?

Comment: (it's based on python:3.6.8-alpine3.9 image)   ---- yep! the issue is relates to volume, I solved it by bind the address to another directory such as `ipc:///tmp/test`, cannot bind to the currently mounted directory from windows

Comment: @KK you’re welcome!